# Why does .css('fontSize') produce different results in Edge?

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-edge

Consider this code (also in [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mywzx4np/)):

```js
document.getElementById("span").innerHTML += $('#input').css('fontSize');
```

```css
span input {
  font-size: inherit;
}

input {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<span id="span" style="font-size: 30px;">
  <input id="input"/>
</span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In Chrome and Firefox, the `.css('fontSize')` will return 30px, in Edge and IE it's 15px. Why does it do that? The DOM Explorer in Edge even shows the 15px in strikethrough, and therefore should take the inherited 30px as the fontSize:

[image]

And the input is rendered with a 30px font, so IE/Edge is picking it up for rendering purposes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: mplungjan and I have updated the question inline with the above ^^

Comment: Sounds like a bug report for either `jQuery` or `Edge`. In the meantime, you could try using `getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('input')).fontSize` and see if it comes out right.

Comment: @mplungjan - Let's be sure to keep the version of jQuery the OP used in the fiddle.

Comment: Ah, Good idea. Missed that

Comment: @Megajin no, it pretty much looks like the JSFiddle. I'm using [autosizeInput](https://github.com/MartinF/jQuery.Autosize.Input) to change the size of input fields. In Edge and IE the width is calculated incorrectly because autosizeInput uses .css('fontSize'), so the input field is just wide enough for the text in default font size.

Comment: @Shlx I assume it is a Bug with the JavaScript - Engine of IE11 and Edge. The computed value is the CSS value instead of the inherited value. You can look into my answer for more details.

Answer (score 9):

**Update:** The [bug below](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9748455/) is now fixed; [FremyCompany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528089/why-does-cssfontsize-produce-different-results-in-edge/40528477?noredirect=1#comment68966948_40528477) says he/she is a program manager from the Edge team and the fix will reach customers in early 2017.

---

It looks very much like an IE and Edge bug. Not having found it, [I reported it](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9748455/).

Here's an update to the snippet that sees what IE/Edge is telling jQuery via `getComputedStyle` or `currentStyle`:

```js
var input = $("#input");
console.log("jQuery: " + input.css('fontSize'));
if (window.getComputedStyle) {
  console.log("getComputedStyle: " + getComputedStyle(input[0]).fontSize);
}
if (input[0].currentStyle) {
  console.log("currentStyle: " + input[0].currentStyle.fontSize);
}
```

```css
span input {
  font-size: inherit;
}

input {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<span id="span" style="font-size: 30px;">
  <input id="input"/>
  <span id="size"></span>
</span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For me, IE11 returns `15px` from both `getComputedStyle` and the Microsoft-specific `currentStyle` property (it's reassuring that they do at least say the same thing):

[image]

So it's not a jQuery bug, it's a Microsoft bug when reporting the size via JavaScript (looks like when `inherit` is the governing rule), even though it's rendering it correctly.

I tried to find a way to make this a grey area, but couldn't think of anything. For instance, according to the spec, having an `input` inside a `span` is entirely valid.

Comment: More specifically it's IE/Edge not recognizing the `inherit` directive when reporting the size. The rendering is correct though.

Comment: I guess it is a problem with the JavaScript - Engine of IE11 and Edge. They compute the CSS value instead of the inherited value.

Comment: Hi, I am a program manager from the Edge team. I would like to report this bug is now fixed in our internal builds. You can expect this fix to reach customers in early 2017.

Comment: @FremyCompany: Nice turn-around!!

Answer (score 0):

Before I get to the real answer I'd like to dig a little into details.

**What is this piece of code doing?**

```
.css();
```

In the [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/css/) they tell us:

> Get the value of a computed style property for the first element in
>   the set of matched elements or set one or more CSS properties for
>   every matched element.

Furthermore:

> The .css() method is a convenient way to get a computed style property
>   from the first matched element, especially in light of the different
>   ways browsers access most of those properties (...)

**So what does computed mean?**

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value):

> the computed value of a CSS property is computed from the specified
>   value by:
>
> - Handling the special values inherit and initial, and
> - Doing the computation needed to reach the value described in the "Computed value" line in the property's summary

**Ok, now that part is clear too. Let's get to the real answer:**

According to [Specifics on CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) there are css-rules with more 'weight' than others have on an HTML element.

Here is the actual order:

1. Style Attribute
2. ID
3. Class, Pseudo Class Attributes
4. Element

According to that rules your input should've taken the inherited 30px from the Style attribute.

**So what is happening in IE11/Edge?**

IE11 and Edge are both computing the CSS Rules wrong. If you change your CSS into only this:

```
span input {
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

It is starting to work. With the information gathered I am assuming that the JavaScript - Engine of both is computing the real CSS value instead of following the CSS rules order.

I've tried to either change the ID and putting a class on the input but still no luck.

I can remember that IE11 and Edge had some problems with inherited CSS and pseudo classes, maybe it is related to that?

Regards,
Megajin